# GHCi instructions from the command line

Tags: haskell, command-line

In the shell you can string commands together, separated by a semicolon:

```
cd ../haskell; rm ./foo; ghc foo.hs; cd ../original_directory
```

It would be great if you could do a similar thing for command-line arguments for ghci, e.g.

```
ghci Foo.hs; a <- getFoo; print a
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ghc -e` for this:

```
sorghum:~/programming% cat test.hs
getFoo = getLine
sorghum:~/programming% ghc test.hs -e 'do { a <- getFoo; print a }'
oenuth
"oenuth"
```

Comment: Cool - I didn't think to look in GHC for it. I think I prefer this method, even though you can't do things like `ghci -v0 Foo.hs <<< ':browse Foo'`

Answer (score 3):

You can run ghci in silent mode and pass the instructions in through its standard input:

> $ cat > ghciPipeTest.hs
>   getFoo = return 37 :: IO Int
>   $ ghci -v0 ghciPipeTest.hs <<<  ' getFoo >>= print '
>   37
>   $

or

> $ ghci -v0 ghciPipeTest.hs <<< $' a <- getFoo \n print a '

(assuming you use a bash-like shell. It also works with actual newlines inside the quotes)

Of course, it also works in non-silent mode, the output just looks a bit strange:

> $ ghci ghciPipeTest.hs <<< $' a<-getFoo \n print a '
>   GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
>   Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
>   Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
>   Loading package base ... linking ... done.
>   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ghciPipeTest.hs, interpreted )
>   Ok, modules loaded: Main.
>   *Main> *Main> 37
>   *Main> Leaving GHCi.